# Morphological opening of volumetric DICOM images

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I understand the concept of opening of 2D binary images but never used such opening on volumetric data as in the code below.

```
nhood = ones([3 3 3]); 
bw = imopen(bw,nhood); % bw is binary volumetric MRI data (28 slices)
```

If I create a structure element of `ones([3 3])`, this means it has three rows and three columns, but in the code above it is `ones([3 3 3])`. First `3` is for number of rows, the second for number of columns, but what is the remaining 3?

Comment: so i have 28 slices in the series then why not ones([3 3 28]), can you please explain

Comment: Why [3 3 28] and not [width height 28] then ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to think about volumes instead of images. You can call the third dimension and slices, and plot each of the slices:

```
bw = imopen(bw,nhood);
[nRows, nCols, nSlics] = size(bw);
disp(['There are ', num2str(nSlics), 'with dimensions ', num2str(nRows), ' x ', num2str(nCols)])

for ii=1:nSlics
   figure();
   imshow(squeeze(bw(:,:,ii)));
   title(['Slice ', num2str(ii), '/', num2str(nSlics)]);
end
```

See all: [techniques-for-visualizing-scalar-volume-datatechniques-for-visualizing-scalar-volume-data](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/techniques-for-visualizing-scalar-volume-data.html)

Answer (score 0):

When working in 3D, you want your structuring element be a 3D cube (containing 3*3*3=27 voxels) within your 3D volume:

[image: Illustration of a cube SE inside a 3D volume]